# What's a Pythonic way to make a non-blocking version of an object?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess, nonblocking

I often use python objects with methods that block until finished, and want to convert these methods to non-blocking versions. I find myself executing the following pattern quite frequently:

1. Define the object
2. Define a function which creates an instance of the object, and parses commands to call methods of the object
3. Define a "parent" object which creates a subprocess running the function defined in step 2, and which duplicates the methods of the original object.

This gets the job done, but involves a lot of tedious repetition of code, and doesn't seem very Pythonic to me. **Is there a standard, better way to do this?**

A highly simplified example to illustrate the pattern I've been using:

```
import ctypes
import Queue
import multiprocessing as mp

class Hardware:
    def __init__(
        self,
        other_init_args):
        self.dll = ctypes.cll.LoadLibrary('hardware.dll')
        self.dll.Initialize(other_init_args)

    def blocking_command(self, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
        """
        This command takes a long time to execute, and blocks while it
        executes. However, while it's executing, we have to coordinate
        other pieces of hardware too, so blocking is bad.
        """
        self.dll.Takes_A_Long_Time(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3)

    def change_settings(self, arg_1, arg_2):
        """
        Realistically, there's tons of other functions in the DLL we
        want to expose as methods. For this example, just one.
        """
        self.dll.Change_Settings(arg_1, arg_2)

    def close(self):
        self.dll.Quit()

def hardware_child_process(
    commands,
    other_init_args):
    hw = Hardware(other_init_args)
    while True:
        cmd, args = commands.recv()
        if cmd == 'start':
            hw.blocking_command(**args)
        elif cmd == 'change_settings':
            hw.change_settings(**args)
        elif cmd == 'quit':
            break
    hw.close()

class Nonblocking_Hardware:
    """
    This class (hopefully) duplicates the functionality of the
    Hardware class, except now Hardware.blocking_command() doesn't
    block other execution.
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        other_init_args):
        self.commands, self.child_commands = mp.Pipe()
        self.child = mp.Process(
            target=hardware_child_process,
            args=(self.child_commands,
                  other_init_args))
        self.child.start()

    def blocking_command(self, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
        """
        Doesn't block any more!
        """
        self.commands.send(
            ('start',
             {'arg_1': arg_1,
              'arg_2': arg_2,
              'arg_3': arg_3}))

    def change_settings(self, arg_1, arg_2):
        self.commands.send(
            ('change_settings',
             {'arg_1': arg_1,
              'arg_2': arg_2}))

    def close(self):
        self.commands.send(('quit', {}))
        self.child.join()
        return None
```

**Backstory:**

I use Python to control hardware, usually through closed-source DLLs that I call using ctypes. Frequently, I end up wanting to call functions from the DLL which block until execution finishes, but I don't want my control code to block. For example, I might be synchronizing a camera with illumination using an analog-out card. The camera DLL "snap" function must be called before the analog-out card can send a trigger pulse to the camera, but the "snap" command blocks, preventing me from activating the analog-out card.

Comment: `ctypes` releases GIL so the standard way to make it non-blocking would be threads -- Twisted `deferToThread()`, `asyncio` `run_in_executor()` or some other way to run a function in a thread pool (`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar by using a metaclass to create non-blocking versions of blocking functions on the object. It allows you to create a non-blocking version of a class just by doing this:

```
class NB_Hardware(object):
    __metaclass__ = NonBlockBuilder
    delegate = Hardware
    nb_funcs = ['blocking_command']
```

I've taken my original implementation, which targeted Python 3 and used a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (I was wrapping blocking I/O calls to make them non-blocking in an `asyncio` context*), and adapted them to use Python 2 and a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. Here's the implementation of the metaclass along with its helper classes:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def runner(self, cb, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(self, cb)(*args, **kwargs)

class _ExecutorMixin():
    """ A Mixin that provides asynchronous functionality.

    This mixin provides methods that allow a class to run
    blocking methods in a ProcessPoolExecutor.
    It also provides methods that attempt to keep the object
    picklable despite having a non-picklable ProcessPoolExecutor
    as part of its state.

    """
    pool_workers = cpu_count()

    def run_in_executor(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        """  Runs a function in an Executor.

        Returns a concurrent.Futures.Future

        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_executor'):
            self._executor = self._get_executor()

        return self._executor.submit(runner, self, callback, *args, **kwargs)

    def _get_executor(self):
        return ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.pool_workers)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if (self._obj and hasattr(self._obj, attr) and
            not attr.startswith("__")):
            return getattr(self._obj, attr)
        raise AttributeError(attr)

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__
        self_dict['_executor'] = None
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
        self._executor = self._get_executor()

class NonBlockBuilder(type):
    """ Metaclass for adding non-blocking versions of methods to a class.  

    Expects to find the following class attributes:
    nb_funcs - A list containing methods that need non-blocking wrappers
    delegate - The class to wrap (add non-blocking methods to)
    pool_workers - (optional) how many workers to put in the internal pool.

    The metaclass inserts a mixin (_ExecutorMixin) into the inheritence
    hierarchy of cls. This mixin provides methods that allow
    the non-blocking wrappers to do their work.

    """
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        nbfunc_list = dct.get('nb_funcs', [])
        existing_nbfuncs = set()

        def find_existing_nbfuncs(d):
            for attr in d:
                if attr.startswith("nb_"):
                    existing_nbfuncs.add(attr)

        # Determine if any bases include the nb_funcs attribute, or
        # if either this class or a base class provides an actual
        # implementation for a non-blocking method.
        find_existing_nbfuncs(dct)
        for b in bases:
            b_dct = b.__dict__
            nbfunc_list.extend(b_dct.get('nb_funcs', []))
            find_existing_nbfuncs(b_dct)

        # Add _ExecutorMixin to bases.
        if _ExecutorMixin not in bases:
            bases += (_ExecutorMixin,)

        # Add non-blocking funcs to dct, but only if a definition
        # is not already provided by dct or one of our bases.
        for func in nbfunc_list:
            nb_name = 'nb_{}'.format(func)
            if nb_name not in existing_nbfuncs:
                dct[nb_name] = cls.nbfunc_maker(func)

        return super(NonBlockBuilder, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        """ Properly initialize a non-blocking wrapper.

        Sets pool_workers and delegate on the class, and also
        adds an __init__ method to it that instantiates the
        delegate with the proper context.

        """
        super(NonBlockBuilder, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        pool_workers = dct.get('pool_workers')
        delegate = dct.get('delegate')
        old_init = dct.get('__init__')
        # Search bases for values we care about, if we didn't
        # find them on the child class.
        for b in bases:
            if b is object:  # Skip object
                continue
            b_dct = b.__dict__
            if not pool_workers:
                pool_workers = b_dct.get('pool_workers')
            if not delegate:
                delegate = b_dct.get('delegate')
            if not old_init:
                old_init = b_dct.get('__init__')

        cls.delegate = delegate

        # If we found a value for pool_workers, set it. If not,
        # ExecutorMixin sets a default that will be used.
        if pool_workers:
            cls.pool_workers = pool_workers

        # Here's the __init__ we want every wrapper class to use.
        # It just instantiates the delegate object.
        def init_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Be sure to call the original __init__, if there
            # was one.
            if old_init:
                old_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

            if self.delegate:
                self._obj = self.delegate(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = init_func

    @staticmethod
    def nbfunc_maker(func):
        def nb_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.run_in_executor(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return nb_func
```

Usage:

```
from nb_helper import NonBlockBuilder
import time


class Hardware:
    def __init__(self, other_init_args):
        self.other = other_init_args

    def blocking_command(self, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
        print("start blocking")
        time.sleep(5)
        return "blocking"

    def normal_command(self):
        return "normal"


class NBHardware(object):
    __metaclass__ = NonBlockBuilder
    delegate = Hardware
    nb_funcs = ['blocking_command']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = NBHardware("abc")
    print "doing blocking call"
    print h.blocking_command(1,2,3)
    print "done"
    print "doing non-block call"
    x = h.nb_blocking_command(1,2,3)  # This is non-blocking and returns concurrent.future.Future
    print h.normal_command()  # You can still use the normal functions, too.
    print x.result()  # Waits for the result from the Future
```

Output:

```
doing blocking call
start blocking
< 5 second delay >
blocking
done
doing non-block call
start blocking
normal
< 5 second delay >
blocking
```

The one tricky piece for you is making sure `Hardware` is picklable. You can probably do that by making `__getstate__` delete the `dll` object, and recreate it in `__setstate__`, similar to what `_ExecutorMixin` does.

You'll also need the Python 2.x [backport of `concurrent.futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures).

Note that there's a bunch of complexity in the metaclass so that they'll work properly with inheritance, and support things like providing custom implementations of `__init__` and the `nb_*` methods. For example, something like this is supported:

```
class AioBaseLock(object):
    __metaclass__ = NonBlockBuilder
    pool_workers = 1
    coroutines = ['acquire', 'release']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._threaded_acquire = False
    def _after_fork(obj):
        obj._threaded_acquire = False
    register_after_fork(self, _after_fork)

def coro_acquire(self, *args, **kwargs):
    def lock_acquired(fut):
        if fut.result():
            self._threaded_acquire = True

    out = self.run_in_executor(self._obj.acquire, *args, **kwargs)
    out.add_done_callback(lock_acquired)
    return out

class AioLock(AioBaseLock):
    delegate = Lock


class AioRLock(AioBaseLock):
    delegate = RLock
```

If you don't need that kind of flexibility, you can simplify the implementation quite a bit:

```
class NonBlockBuilder(type):
    """ Metaclass for adding non-blocking versions of methods to a class.  

    Expects to find the following class attributes:
    nb_funcs - A list containing methods that need non-blocking wrappers
    delegate - The class to wrap (add non-blocking methods to)
    pool_workers - (optional) how many workers to put in the internal pool.

    The metaclass inserts a mixin (_ExecutorMixin) into the inheritence
    hierarchy of cls. This mixin provides methods that allow
    the non-blocking wrappers to do their work.

    """
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        nbfunc_list = dct.get('nb_funcs', [])

        # Add _ExecutorMixin to bases.
        if _ExecutorMixin not in bases:
            bases += (_ExecutorMixin,)

        # Add non-blocking funcs to dct, but only if a definition
        # is not already provided by dct or one of our bases.
        for func in nbfunc_list:
            nb_name = 'nb_{}'.format(func)
            dct[nb_name] = cls.nbfunc_maker(func)

        return super(NonBlockBuilder, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        """ Properly initialize a non-blocking wrapper.

        Sets pool_workers and delegate on the class, and also
        adds an __init__ method to it that instantiates the
        delegate with the proper context.

        """
        super(NonBlockBuilder, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        pool_workers = dct.get('pool_workers')
        cls.delegate = dct['delegate']

        # If we found a value for pool_workers, set it. If not,
        # ExecutorMixin sets a default that will be used.
        if pool_workers:
            cls.pool_workers = pool_workers

        # Here's the __init__ we want every wrapper class to use.
        # It just instantiates the delegate object.
        def init_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._obj = self.delegate(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = init_func

    @staticmethod
    def nbfunc_maker(func):
        def nb_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.run_in_executor(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return nb_func
```

<sub>* The original code is [here](https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing/blob/master/aioprocessing/executor.py), for reference.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

One method I've used to launch class methods asynchronously is to create a pool and call a few function aliases with [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) instead of directly calling the class methods.

Say you have an even simpler version of your classes:

```
class Hardware:
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff
        return

    def blocking_command(self, arg1):
        self.stuff.call_function(arg1)
        return
```

At the top level of your module, define a new function that looks like this:

```
def _blocking_command(Hardware_obj, arg1):
    return Hardware_obj.blocking_command(Hardware_obj, arg1)
```

Since the class and this "alias" function are both defined at the top level of the module, they are pickleable and you can kick it off using the multiprocessing library:

```
import multiprocessing

hw_obj = Harware(stuff)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

results_obj = pool.apply_async(_blocking_command, (hw_obj, arg1))
```

The results of your function calls will be available in the results object. I like this approach because it uses a relatively small amount of code to make parallelization a lot easier. Specifically, it only adds a few two-line functions instead of any classes, and there are no extra imports required besides multiprocessing.

Notes:

1. Don't use this for methods that need to modify the objects attributes, but it works fine if it is used *after* all of the class' attributes have been set, effectively treating the class attributes as "read-only".
2. You can also use this approach inside a class method to launch other class methods, you just have to explicitly pass "self". This could allow you to move your floating "hardware_child_process" function into the class. it would still act as a dispatcher of a bunch of asynchronous processes, but it would centralize that functionality in your Hardware class.